# How to reset busy serial ports in java

Tags: java, serial-port, jssc

Im working on an application that will communicate with an external pin-pad through USB/Serial Port.

Sometimes Im facing the problem that the operation wasn't finished properly and my pinpad gets stuck inside an unfinished transaction and i can't manage to start a new one.

What I'm looking for here is a way to kill all serial port connections and restart them within java code or an external script that could be called from my code when I get the 'busy port exception'.

- Im using JSSC for serial communication.

Answer (score 0):

Please describe the work flow I mean using the pin. Getting port busy exception means the way you have written code needs to be refined. You can also try pyserial, serialpundit or fazecast libraries etc.